# how to sort Array based on column value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am using Javascript, and have an Array with four columns as following-:

```
 GroupType  GroupName   GroupEmail Id   MembersCount
Authorized App  Name A      a@domain.com    0,

Unauthorizedd AppName B     b@domain.com    2
```

I want to sort by the first column so i can see all the Authorized App on top.

Please help me with this.

thank you.

Comment: please add the array with the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Return a negative number for any sub-array that has `"Authorized App"` as the first member, otherwise return a positive number.

```
data.sort((a, b) => a[0] === "Authorized App" ? -1 : 1);
```

Returning a negative number moves `a` toward the start of the list.

Or you may get a more stable sort if you return `0` instead of `-1`. Not sure. I don't think a stable sort is guaranteed either way.

Comment: Well, one should ensure that two items, when compared against each other, don't return inconsistent comparisons... With that respect, perhaps `data.sort((a, b) => ((a[0] === "Authorized App" || a[0] > b[0]) && b[0] !== "Authorized App" ? 1 : 0) - ((b[0] === "Authorized App" || b[0] > a[0]) && a[0] !== "Authorized App" ? 1 : 0);` or something? It gets complicated quite quickly... :/

Comment: @Sebivor: Perhaps. If the list is otherwise unsorted, then in likely doesn't make a difference. Or maybe there's some other criteria that should be used. Just working from the limited info provided. But thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: thank you mates, there are around 4000 rows where the data in first column's value is either "Authorized App" or "Unauthorized App", however values in column 2,3 and 4 are names, emaild and member count which is usually different in each row.
Also, am using Google Apps Script so some of the javascript is not supported such as =>

Comment: @GelaRam Use `function(a, b) { return expr; }` instead of `(a, b) => expr`, in that case...